# Starting activity in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-framelayout

I need to start a new activity once the user clicks in a button which is rendered in a FrameLayout. It renders the button which I want the user to click, but of course it's not doing anything right now.

The code of the class is the following, but I can't call the startActivity(intent).

```
public class TopBarView extends FrameLayout {

    private ImageView mLogoImage;
    private Button mInfoButton;

    public TopBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TopBarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public TopBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_bar, null);

        mLogoImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageLogo);
        mInfoButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.infoButton);

        mInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // We load & render the view for the information screen
//              Intent i = new Intent();
//              i.setClass(getContext(), MeerActivity.class);
//              startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        addView(view);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// We load & render the view for the information screen
//              Intent i = new Intent();
//              i.setClass(getContext(), MeerActivity.class);
//              startActivity(i);
}
```

To :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// We load & render the view for the information screen
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(v.getContext(), MeerActivity.class);
    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

Note : Might be better to assign the onclicklistener via the activity you are using so the TopBarView is a bit more reusable in case you ever want to use something other than MeerActivity as a target. No biggy tho.